# Насколько важен пинг до NTP-сервера?

Tags: синхронизация, ping, 3g, ntp

Необходимо синхронизировать время на нескольких приборах на базе Debian. Но появился вопрос. Так как приборы эти с интернетом связаны через 3G-модемы, то ping до любого сервера может быть от 30 до 3000 ms, и это обусловлено только "тараканами" у оператора связи и уровнем сигнала. Насколько важен пинг при синхронизации времени и как можно решить данную проблему, если она все же существенна?

Comment: В принципе протокол NTP задержки умеет рассчитывать и компенсировать. По идее должен справляться, особенно если не разовое получение времени, а полноценный запущенный ntpd на каждом устройстве. Хотя каков у него "запас прочности" по задержкам не знаю